# How can I change the name in irctc eticket?

Tags: indian-railways, irctc

I booked a irctc ticket online for my friend, now I misspelled the name by one alphabet, so is there any way to change the name here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a change in the name of a passenger on your e-ticket, IRCTC (Indian Railway Catering and Tourism Operation), which handles the catering, tourism and online ticketing operations of the Indian Railways, offers the facility of doing so. To avail this facility, customers need to approach the nearest railway reservation office with 'Electronic Reservation Slip' print out and the original photo identity proof of one of the passengers travelling in the ticket. One needs to visit the office at least 24 hours before the scheduled departure of the train as per extant Railway rules, said IRCTC on its official website, irctc.co.in.

Here are key things to know about passenger's name change in IRCTC e-ticket:

IRCTC reservation offices can change passenger name against a request from the passenger, as per the existing railway rules applicable to tickets booked through railways counters.

The passenger is required to make a request for name change in e-ticket in writing 24 hours before the scheduled departure of the train to the nearest railway reservation office.

The e-ticket can also be transferred to another member of the passenger's family - father, mother, brother, sister, son, daughter, husband and wife. The passenger should bring the 'electronic reservation slip' print out along with photo identity card proof in original and a proof for blood relation with the new passenger, said IRCTC.

IRCTC also allows a passenger who is a government servant proceeding on duty and appropriate authority, to make a request in writing 24 hours before the scheduled departure of the train.

However, such request can be granted once only.